# This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Opening Xamarin Android Project properties gives the following error after I upgraded VS2017 to 15.5.3 (latest version). It keeps popping up such error. This project was working fine 2 months ago.

```
This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed
```

[image: error message]

Anybody found a solution yet? It is mentioned in [VS Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165160/propert-is-not-valid-when-the-sdk-is-not-installed.html) as well last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repairing from Visual Studio Installation fixed this issue.

[image: Repair screenshot]